# resizing browser does not resize div correctly - so simple what am I doing wrong?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

When I shrink the browser width I expect the header div to shrink along with the browser and take up the entire width of the page.  Instead the div stops at the browser width and then there is blank space to the right and a horizontal scroll bar.  This seems to be a problem with the way I'm using bootstrap but I can't figure it out.  Any help appreciated

I'm using the latest minified bootstrap css in my project and have completely simplified my layout below.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en"> 

 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap.min.css" />
 </head>

 <body>
  <div class="row">
   <div class="header">
    <div class="container">
     <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

css:

```
body {
 background-color: #CDE0E4;
 width: 100%;
}

.header {
 position: relative;
 height:120px;
 background-color:#CDE0E4;
 box-shadow: 0 0px 15px #272727;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried `width:100%` on `.row` and `.header`?

Comment: yes I tried that but still the same problem of a scrollbar and empty space on the  right

Comment: I think I need the style.css and boostrap.min.css to see what happens. Please add it to the jsFiddle I created, http://jsfiddle.net/PJcUu/.

Comment: thanks for taking the time to help! http://jsfiddle.net/PJcUu/1/

Comment: You shouldn't have to set a body width explicitly unless you want the immediate child containers to have a percentage width of the body. If that's the case, try resetting the margins and paddings of the body element to 0;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is **fluid layout** ([see the docs](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#layouts)). This term means that your content takes most available width and is resized when browser window is resized. In this case you should use `.container-fluid` and `.row-fluid` instead of their unsuffixed versions.

But you are misusing some of Bootstrap's classes.

### .row

Is used when you want to create a multi-column layout. For this you have `.span*` classes to use inside it ([see the docs for examples](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#gridSystem)).

### .container

Is used when you want your content to have a white space on the sides (it will be `20px` for `.container-fluid` and maximum available for `.container`).

### .header

If you are using HTML5 (which you do by declaring `<!doctype html>`), why not to use `<header>` instead of `<div class="header">`?

Comment: Thanks Pavlo, that was the one!

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="container">
```

should come at the top. Row is nested inside container and finally the column is nested inside row. You have reversed the order. That is one problem with your code.