# Boostrap - Background does extend 100% width when resizing browser

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

For my rails application, I am using bootstrap.  When I shrink the width of my browser window below around 900 pixels, the background stops extending the complete width of the browser with about 20px of space on each side. I took at look at this ([resizing browser does not resize div correctly - so simple what am I doing wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12396380/resizing-browser-does-not-resize-div-correctly-so-simple-what-am-i-doing-wrong)) but still could not get it to work.

Question: How do I adjust code so that when I resize my browser window width below X amount, it does not create the space?

application.js

```
//= require bootstrap
```

**layouts/_header.html.erb**

```
<div class = "middlebar">
  <div class="container">
    <p class="navbar-text">
        Hello World!
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

**styles.css.scss**

```
.middlebar {
  padding: 0px 0;
  text-align: left;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  border-top: 1px solid #fff;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #ddd;
  margin-bottom: -20px;
}
```

Before Resize:

[image: pic 1]

After Resize:

[image: pic 2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twitter bootstrap have a file called "responsive.css" and there is a rule for media queries that less then 767px width the whole container div get 100% width, and the body get a `padding-left` and `padding-right` about 20px, just remove that line of the rule and you will get the result that you want...

Just for you concern that `20px` is good for mobiles so think twice before you remove it.

Comment: Thanks. But how do I remove the line of the rule? I tried adding margin-left:-20px and margin-right:-20px to my .middlebar class, but then my text inside the container does not align to the left of the container on the resize. Any idea?

Comment: I will just use margin-left/right:-20px and use if current_page?(path) to adjust for sections of the page where I don't mind it reaching the edge for mobiles.